# Running python with different permissions

Tags: python, linux, permissions, suid

I'm trying to run a python script as other user (not root) which is also a system user with no shell. I understand that I can't set suid flag directly on the script so I wrote a C++ wrapper.

wrapper.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << geteuid() << std::endl;

    setgid(getgid());
    setuid(getuid());

    execl("/usr/bin/python2.6", "/usr/bin/python2.6", "test.py", NULL);
}
```

And set following permissions

```
sudo chown NoShellUser:NoShellGroup /path/to/wrapper
sudo chmod 7755 /path/to/wrapper
```

Finally, to try it out I have a python script

```
import sys
import getpass
import os
import pwd
print "VERSION:", sys.version
print "USER:", getpass.getuser(), pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())
print "EUSER:", pwd.getpwuid(os.geteuid())
```

With following permissions if that matters at all

```
sudo chown NoShellUser:NoShellGroup /path/to/test.py
sudo chmod 7755 /path/to/test.py
```

Now when I run this whole thing as user "test" I see this:

```
255                                                    # UID of NoShellUser
VERSION: 2.6.8 (unknown, Apr 12 2012, 20:59:36)        # Don't know where that comes from
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)]                # Don't know where that comes from
USER: test pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='test', pw_passwd='hash', pw_uid=20804, pw_gid=604, pw_gecos='Name Surname', pw_dir='/home/test', pw_shell='/bin/bash')
EUSER: pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='test', pw_passwd='hash', pw_uid=20804, pw_gid=604, pw_gecos='Name Surname', pw_dir='/home/test', pw_shell='/bin/bash')
```

As you can see the effective user is still "test". Can somebody please point to me what am I doing wrong, because I looked at few examples already and they all seems to be showing exact same thing more or less?

Comment: Why don't you just use `sudo`???

Comment: Can you explain what this program is being used for, and why it needs to be run under its own account?  Depending on the situation, there may be a better approach available to you.

Comment: Well it's a queue which runs executables which come from a safe source in terms that there is nothing harmful in the code, but not safe in terms of they mostly written by not professional developers, so there might be bugs allowing escalation of permissions (there will be untrasted text input to this applications). That's why I want it to be as isolated as possible. In the end I will be putting it to cron owned by this same system (uid<500) user, but from time to time I will need to start it myself, from web interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrapper is slightly wrong - try this instead

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
  std::cout << "Real user " << getuid() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Effective user " << geteuid() << std::endl;

  setregid(getegid(), getegid());
  setreuid(geteuid(), geteuid());

  std::cout << "Real user " << getuid() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Effective user " << geteuid() << std::endl;

  execl("/usr/bin/python2.6", "/usr/bin/python2.6", "test.py", NULL);
}
```

It sets the real and effective user/group ids to the effective group id before execing the python script.